Finding onsite research assistant job in Europe/UK
Is it possible to find research assistant jobs after getting a Master's degree in Europe/UK for a non-EU citizen? If so, how should one apply for such jobs? The university websites only offer few RA posts in very limited majors, is it common to send emails to professors to ask for such opportunities?
Temporary positions like this seem to vary in different countries. Are there any countries that one can have a better chance in finding these posts?

Is there a specific reason why you are looking for RA instead of PhD positions?

For me there are two reasons. I want to visit my girlfriend who is currently studying in Europe and I'm looking for a research topic for my PhD. Applying for a PhD or an online research experience are not really feasible because of this...

In the UK all jobs like this will be advertised on university websites, or on jobs.ac.uk (usually both).
Most universities insist that all abstinence positions are advertised and recruited openly. The law in the UK says that employers must have demonstrated that the have made significant efforts to recruit someone from the UK before they can recruit someone from overseas,  and most unis interpret this as having advertised it to UK people for a month or so. Further, unpaid assistantships are illegal.
You should also be aware that of your girlfriend is in the EU, moving between the EU and the UK, even for short visits is not a easy as it used to be,  particularly without an EU passport.

Thanks for the answer! So is it safe to assume that looking for potential vacancy by sending emails will most likely not work?

Probably not. Still, you might hit on someone that is about to advertise a job and can give you a heads up. Or can put together an artifically specific job description where only you would be qualified for the job. Its a long shot though.
